# XP - ping changes routing table?

Tags: networking, routing, ping, windows-xp

I have got a real strange behaviour with one of my XP-Sp3 machines.

Setup:
  A Server in the lan (192.168.5.0) proviedes access to all roadwarriors in 10.8.0.0
  The DCHP has a static route for all clients pronouncing 192.168.5.235 as gateway for 10.8.0.0

All Clients can ping & access the vpn-machines; everything works like a charm

But one Xp-Sp3 is not willing to connect to them. It gets all the same routes as any other sytem in the lan and I trippel-checked - there are no static routes on this machine

When I ping any 10.8.0.0 device from this machine, the first two packaged work like a charm; but the next two (and any package after them) fail and get lost.

When I look back into the routing table: There is a new route; a special one just for the device I pinged, which points to the right gateway - but which wasn't there earlier...

As Long as this route exists the machine can't ping anything on 10.8.0.0.
  But if I remove the route by hand: The next to ping packages work fine...

Has anybody got an idea about that? Anybody every seen such a behaviour? Any hint / help / tip is greatly appreachiated!

thx in advance

Corelgott

Ps: I attach an image of the cmd to clarify things - its in german, but reading a routing table shouldn't be that hard...

[strage?! http://two-nerds.com/route.jpg](http://two-nerds.com/route.jpg)

Comment: Progressive JPG ftw!

Comment: More like Progressive JPG...... wtf! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Is the netmask for the 10.8.0.0 route correct? From what I see here, I think you would want 255.255.0.0 instead of 255.255.255.255. What type of VPN are you using?

EDIT: What do the routing tables on the working machines show when you perform the same procedure?

Comment: Hi Jed,

thanks for your response! You were right, that seemd to be a mistake! Cleaning the routing-table fixed that entry and changed it to 10.8.0.0 Mask 255.255.255.0 as delivered by the dhcp. None the less i can't ping the 10.8.0.10 anymore (not even twice)

The VPN we are using is an OpenVPN, which has been working fine for years! Bringing new machines into the net never ever has been a problem. Btw. I just checked, there is no Firewall / Av or additional protocol installed on the server. It just doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be the result of ICMP REDIRECT packets (essentially, a router can elect to say "this is a better route AND it is local to your network" when its next hop is on the same network as the source).